# Gap appears when dragging View - Android

Tags: android, animation

I have a `LinearLayout` with a left component and right component. There is  no gap in between. Statically, the view looks fine. However, when I drag via `View.OnTouchListener`, a narrow vertical gap appears out of nowhere, which is extremely annoying. Does anyone know how I can fix it?

##### MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnTouchListener {
    private lateinit var knobView: LinearLayout
    private lateinit var knobLeftView: View
    private lateinit var knobRightView: View
    private var currentX = 0F

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        knobLeftView = findViewById(R.id.knob_left)
        knobRightView = findViewById(R.id.knob_right)
        knobView = findViewById(R.id.knob)
        knobView.setOnTouchListener(this)
    }

    override fun onTouch(view: View, event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        val destX = event.rawX
        when (event.action) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                currentX = destX
            }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                val deltaX = destX - currentX
                knobView.animate()
                    .xBy(deltaX)
                    .duration = 0
                currentX = destX
            }
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

##### activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipChildren="false">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/knob"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <View
            android:id="@+id/knob_left"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/knob_radius"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/knob_size"
            android:background="@drawable/background_left" />
        <View
            android:id="@+id/knob_right"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/knob_radius"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/knob_size"
            android:background="@drawable/background_right" />
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like a background issue Try assigning it an Icon or a dark color like black ..

Comment: I need to use 2 semi circles in the real app. Also, using black did not fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this probably could be a rendering issue. But this could be solved by changing the leading margin instead of the x position:

```
override fun onTouch(view: View, event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
    val destX = event.rawX

    when (event.action) {
        MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
            currentX = destX
        }

        MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
            val deltaX = destX - currentX
//                knobView.animate()
//                    .xBy(deltaX)
//                    .duration = 0

            val params = knobView.layoutParams as FrameLayout.LayoutParams
            params.leftMargin = (params.leftMargin + deltaX).toInt()
            knobView.layoutParams = params

            currentX = destX
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

As the animation duration is set to 0, this would have no much affect to omit using the animation

[image]

Comment: Wow, amazing! Thank you so much! I never would have thought of doing this in a million years!